# Values are not getting deleted in a table when DELETE command seems to be working fine

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, datagridview, delete-row

I have developed management system for an organization. I have many datagridviews in my forms. And for every delete operation, i have the same command (IN THERE RESPECTIVE CELL CONTENT CLICK EVENTS) as you could see below. At one place its working just fine and values are getting deleted from tables. But in another table, when i click button in a datagridview named delete so inside cell content click event i am supposed to delete the record of that entity from database. On clicking, row gets removed but when i just open my database, values are still there.

My coide is here:

```
    private void data_grid2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Result's tab's Gridview
            int m = 0;
            int currentRow = int.Parse(e.RowIndex.ToString());
            try
            {
                string name = data_grid2.CurrentRow.Cells["RollNo"].Value.ToString();
                m = int.Parse(name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                throw;
            }

            if (data_grid2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == editButton && currentRow >= 0)
            {

            }

            else if (data_grid2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == deleteButton && currentRow >= 0)
            {
                string queryDeleteString = "DELETE * FROM finalResult where RollNo = " + m + "";
                OleDbCommand sqlDelete = new OleDbCommand();
                sqlDelete.CommandText = queryDeleteString;
                sqlDelete.Connection = database;
                sqlDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string queryString = "SELECT RollNo, RegYear, faculty, program, examNature, finalmarksObt, totalMarks, Percentage FROM finalResult";
                loadResults(queryString);

            }
}
```

What could be wrong behind the scene?
[image]

Comment: What is your connectionstring? Are you using the shortcut DataDirectory? And if yes do you have you MDB file listed between the project files with Copy To Output Directory set to Copy Always?

Comment: string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=RAIMS.accdb

Comment: All right this means that you use a database located in the same startup path of your app. In Visual Studio this is the BIN\DEBUG folder. Do you have your ACCDB file listed between the project files? If yes what is its property Copy To Output Directory?

Comment: Sir its been set to Copy always.

Comment: Well for now i have deleted it and copied a new one to this location which i had created as a backup earlier. Now its working fine.

Comment: Well was it because would there be a conflict between both files?

Comment: Copy Always means every time you run a debug session of VS the original ACCDB file is copied by VS from your project folder to your BIN\DEBUG. Destroying the changes made by the previous session. Usually the file in project folder is there ready for deployment, with the base data that you need to send to your customers. The one in BIN\DEBUG is your working data. Change the property to _Copy if Newer_. So only when you change the schema or data it will be copied to bin\debug. Be aware that Access changes its filestamp just opening it also if you don't make any change

Comment: Thanks Sir for your very kind concern. I will surely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

My Access is a little rusty, but I believe the delete syntax is still the same as Sql Server

```
string queryDeleteString = "DELETE * FROM finalResult where RollNo = " + m + "";
```

Your syntax is invalid since you are trying to delete *.  It is simply just delete.

```
string queryDeleteString = "DELETE FROM finalResult where RollNo = " + m + "";
```

As an aside, this code is ripe for sql injection.

Comment: Thanks for your concern Sir but its not working as well. Can you tell me as could it be caused by disturbance of permissions on the folder where my database resides?

Comment: And yes i would surely be shielding it with anti-sql injection technique Sir. Thanks alot for pointing it out.

Comment: Have you verified that m is the idea that you think it is and exists in the database?

Comment: Yes Sir I had verified. Now i have removed a database and copied a new one which i had created for the sake of backup. Now its working fine. What i reckon is that i had also added data source in my project for nothing owing to which i had got two database files. Which i think that probably both were having conflicts. Isn't it?

Comment: There's honestly not enough information for me to know either way.  That said, glad that it seems to be working for you :)